# How to undo view Y change when scroll up?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a textview in the lower half of my view controller and I am animating its top constraint to change Y for a more "full screen" look when you swipe up/scroll down, but I don't know how to undo it in reverse so it goes back to its original position

Here's my code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var viewAllTextViews: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var topOfViewAllTextViews: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func growViewAllTextViews(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        self.topOfViewAllTextViews.constant = -220
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

Updated:

I'm getting an error when I try to run my updated code. The error is "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and my debug console shows topOfViewAllTextViews = (NSLayoutConstraint?)nil.

Here's my code as recommended:

```
@IBAction func growViewAllTextViews(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let velocity = sender.velocity(in: myView)
    if velocity.y > 0 {
        self.topOfViewAllTextViews.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    } else {
        self.topOfViewAllTextViews.constant = -215 // error here
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Here's where I've set up the constraints in Storyboard. I had a height<= but deleted that to see if that could be it, but still getting error.

[image]

Comment: Just add back the 220 and call `layoutIfNeeded` when you want it to go back.

Comment: How do I link it to a gesture in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the pan direction with the **velocity** of the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

```
@IBAction func growViewAllTextViews(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let velocity = gesture.velocity(in: yourView)

    if velocity.y > 0 {
        self.topOfViewAllTextViews.constant = 220
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    } else {
        self.topOfViewAllTextViews.constant = -220
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```